# Change grouped UITableview border size

Tags: iphone, uitableview, border

I know how to add a border to the tableview using:

```
myTableview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor
myTableview.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
```

Setting the border like this results in a square border around the bounds of the tableview not the bounds of the grouped cells in the tableview. Using a similar idea on the cells makes a square border around the bounds of the cell but not the rounded edges.

There doesnt seem to be any way of changing the seperator width on the cells either. Is it possible to make a border around a grouped tableview?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking.  There is a `cornerRadius` property on CALayer in iOS 3.0 and later.

Comment: CornerRadius will only round the edges of on object. I think he is looking for a physical border to go around the UITableView.

Comment: @WrightCS: If you use cornerRadius in combination with the borderColor and borderWidth properties, you will get a rounded border.

Answer (score 0):

To use **`.layer`**, make sure you `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`. But `UITableView` does not have the **border** properties you are looking for, so unfortunately your code will not work.

You can however either place the `UITableView` on a `UIImageView` with an image that has a border which would be the easiest solution, or you can use `CoreGraphics` to draw out the border which would be a lot more work.

Comment: Ive imported all the correct frameworks to make .layer work. Using an UIImage seems a little sloppy. Also having problems implementing rounded corners on cells with a background image or background color.

Comment: Well, as I stated, UITableVIew will not take to a border property, so thats out of the question. Using an image for the border is not at all sloppy, opens the door for creativity in my opinion. AS far as the cells corners go, I am not sure what you are talking about. A single cell row will have rounded corners, where-as a table with 3+ rows will only have the 1st and last cells with rounded corners.

Comment: They do have rounded corners on the default tableview cell. If i add a background image or change the color the top and bottom cells in the group lose the rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above, but Ive decided in the end to go with this method for customizing grouped tables:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Not as programmatic as I would have liked but it does the job brilliantly. Would like to think that this will be something Apple will make easier to implement in future XCode updates.